# Enlarge merged cell depending on length of text

Tags: excel, vba

I have an input text ***without*** any linebreaks, this text is used somewhere else. At this "somewhere else" place I would like to enlarge the cell in the height direction depending on the size of the input text. I could increase the height of the cell (see "solution A") or first add new lines under and them merge them together (see "solution B").
I would prefer the solution B but if it's not possible I guess only "solution A" remains.

My question is: How can I get the "virtual height" of the cell A5? The height now is just the height of this one line cell.

[image: example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy solution for that, but try the following workaround.

The start is the cell `A5` merged over the range `A5:G5` with your desired text. Then run `Example_AutoFitAndMerge`.

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Start with this data in your sheet.</sup>*

Then we do the following:

1. We save the original dimensions of the cell `A5`.
2. We get the merged range `A5:G5` and its width.
3. We unmerge and resize A5 to the same width as `A5:G5`.
   *Note that this re-size has to be done 3 times as Excel is weird in how it handles column-widths.*
4. Then we make sure the text is wrapped and autofit the row height.
   [image]
   *<sup>Image 2: This is just to get the "virtual" new height.</sup>*
5. Now we have the new row hight.
6. We re-merge the cells (undo the unmerge)
7. We re-size `A5` to its original dimensions.
   *Note: again 3 times.*
8. We calculate the amount of rows we need for the new height.
9. We add the necessary amount of rows.
10. We merge them.

[image]
*<sup>Image 3: Result.</sup>*

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example_AutoFitAndMerge()
    AutoFitAndMerge Range("A5")
End Sub

Public Sub AutoFitAndMerge(ByVal Cell As Range)
    ' save original height and width of the cell
    Dim OriginalHeight As Double
    OriginalHeight = Cell.Height
    
    Dim OriginalWidth As Double
    OriginalWidth = Cell.Width
    
    ' get the merged range and its width
    Dim MergedRange As Range
    Set MergedRange = Cell.MergeArea
        
    Dim MergedWidth As Double
    MergedWidth = MergedRange.Width

    With Cell
        ' unmerge and make width of column same width as merged cells and autofit
        .UnMerge
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 3
            .Parent.Columns(Cell.Column).ColumnWidth = MergedWidth * (Cell.ColumnWidth / Cell.Width)
        Next i
        
        ' autofit it to get the height
        .WrapText = True
        .EntireRow.AutoFit
        
        ' get height
        Dim NewHeight As Double
        NewHeight = Cell.Height
        
        ' re-merge and set original column width and height
        MergedRange.Merge False
        For i = 1 To 3
            .Parent.Columns(Cell.Column).ColumnWidth = OriginalWidth * (Cell.ColumnWidth / Cell.Width)
            .Parent.Rows(Cell.Row).RowHeight = OriginalHeight * (Cell.RowHeight / Cell.Height)
        Next i
        
        ' calculate the amount of rows needed for the new merge
        Dim AmountOfRows As Double
        AmountOfRows = NewHeight / OriginalHeight
        
        ' insert that amount below
        With MergedRange.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Resize(RowSize:=AmountOfRows - 1, ColumnSize:=MergedRange.Columns.Count)
            .Insert xlShiftDown
        End With
        
        ' and merge them
        With MergedRange.Resize(RowSize:=AmountOfRows)
            .Merge
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that this works as long as there is no other data in the row that messes up the `.AutoFit` of the row height.

And of course you might want to turn of `ScreenUpdating` to prevent intense flickering. As there is a lot of resizing going on.

Comment: Hello @Pᴇʜ , thanks for your response, it's very well explained.
I didn't had the time yet to implement your code into my project but will notify when it will have been done.

Comment: why do you do two times these loops with 3 iterations ? You don't use the i value or something ?

Comment: @smirnoff103 Didn't you see my note? *"Note that this re-size has to be done 3 times as Excel is weird in how it handles column-widths"* There is a weird bug/behavior in Excel that makes it only accurate if it is run at least 3 times. If you don't do that the resize is not accurate. See it as an numeric iteration procedure to get the the result we want. If you do it only once it migth not be the expected result.